# %ENV doesn't work and I cannot use shared library

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi, dbd, env

I cannot use `%ENV` var on my Perl script to use Oracle libs.

```
BEGIN {
    $ORACLE_HOME = "/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64";
    $LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "$ORACLE_HOME/lib";
    $ORACLE_SID="prod";
    $ENV{ORACLE_SID}=$ORACLE_SID;
    $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}= $ORACLE_HOME;
    $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}= $LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
};
```

If I print `$ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'}` and `$ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'}` all seems ok but, when I run my script I have the error:

> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
>    at (eval 3) line 3
>   Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 3.
>   Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
>    at persistence.perl line 22

Searching on web I saw that the correct way to set env vars on Perl is to use `%ENV` hash.

Exporting `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` through unix shell (`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`) it works correctly. Any advice?

Comment: It has been a long time since I have had to work with Oracle and Perl and I remember that one of the libraries that the Perl module needs doesn't install with the developer install.  I would have to extract the files and pull the library out of the database package.

Comment: But is strange, because if I export those paths through shell, it works correctly. Seems not a problem related to missing libraries

Comment: Shell script wrapper is how we always did it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable has to be set *before* your program starts — before `perl` itself is loaded. Changing it in `BEGIN{}` will affect new *programs* that you start, but it won't affect the loading of *shared libraries* — in this case (although I've never used the DBD::Oracle) you're loading an Oracle `.so` into the already-running program, so it's “too late” to change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The dynamic linker `/lib/ld.so` (or so) is started before `perl`, so by the time your script is compiled and `BEGIN{}` runs, it's already set up.

You *could* try to re-exec your script as its own successor or something*, but a short shell script is almost certainly going to be the simplest solution:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64/lib
  export ORACLE_SID=prod
  exec /usr/local/bin/your-db-program "$@"
```

*- this would be kinda crazy, but TIMTOWTDI:

```
  eval { 
     use DBD::Oracle foo bar baz; …
  };
  if ($@ =~ /install_driver\(Oracle\) failed/) {
     $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} .= ':/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64/lib';
     $ENV{ORACLE_SID} = 'prod';
     warn "Restarting with LD_LIBRARY_PATH reset:\n\n$@\n";
     exec { $0 } $0 => @ARGV;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a few test scripts to verify that the environment is being set when you change `%ENV`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

BEGIN {
    my $foo = "bar-bar";
    $ENV{FOO} = "$foo";
}

system qq(/bin/echo printing out \$FOO);
```

This prints out:

```
printing out bar-bar
```

which is what I expected.

I then tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

BEGIN {
    my $foo = "bar-bar";
    $ENV{FOO} = "$foo";
}


system qq(./test.sh);
```

and created a `test.sh` program that looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

echo This is what I got: $FOO;
```

In this case, my Perl script is running `test.sh` which prints out the value of the `$FOO` environment variable that was set in my Perl script. Running `test.pl` I get:

```
This is what I got bar-bar
```

This shows that not only is Perl setting the environment variables, but that it is also exporting those variables, so called shell scripts have access to them.

You can try a similar technique to verify that both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` are being set before they're used. I suspect you'll find that this is indeed happening, but that your program still isn't working when you set `%ENV`.

This points to one conclusion: Setting the environment for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` might be occurring too late by the time your Perl script starts. I believe the operating system examines `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before Perl starts. I found this doing a search on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable you set to **give the run-time shared library loader (ld.so) an extra set of directories to look for when searching for shared libraries**. Multiple directories can be listed, separated with a colon (:). This list is prepended to the existing list of compiled-in loader paths for a given executable, and any system default loader paths.

So, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for the `ld.so` runtime shared library loader, If `ld.so` has already been loaded, changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't do anything.

I found a similar discussion on [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=28533). I noticed someone found [rerunning `env`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=28554) seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to modify /etc/ld.so.conf

On CentOS/RHEL 6.4, you could create etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle with this:

```
/oracle/sw/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib
```

Obviously, modify as suits your ORACLE_HOME.

Then run

```
ldconfig -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `export` commands into the start up script for your unix shell which you should have permission to edit. That way, the environment variables will be set whenever you start a new shell and all scripts and programs that use Oracle will pick them up.

Answer (score -1):

I just went through something similar. I had to make sure that the Oracle environment was setup before anything else called it. Make sure the `BEGIN` block is before any other "use" statements. In my case, something was being called in Apache's httpd.conf file, so I had to setup my environment there instead of in my package.

Comment: Yes, my `BEGIN` block is before everything

Comment: Is this in a web environment? If so, it is possible that something loading DBD::Oracle before it makes it to your script.

Comment: No, it is not in a web enviroment. It's just a script that I run from shell